# pointwise purity for character sheaves on a wonderful compactification

Tags: algebraic-groups, perverse-sheaves

Consider the minimal (Goresky-MacPherson) extension of a character sheaf on a semi-simple (say) adjoint group to its wonderful compactification. Is that extension pointwise pure?